# Ethereum Wallet cannot complie "msg.sender.send"

Tags: solidity, compiler, cryptokitties

I have been using Ethereum Wallet to compile and deploy contracts. Now I got this error when trying to test the code in `CryptoKittyCore`. It failed to compile with this message

> ```
> Failure condition of 'eth_compileSolidity' ignored. Consider using 'transfer' instead.
>         msg.sender.send(autoBirthFee);
>         ^---------------------------^
> ```

My Ethereum Wallet version is 0.9.3

Comment: I assume this is a warning, not an error, right? It's pointing out that "send" can fail, and your code is not checking for that failure.

Answer (score 0):

This message should not be a reason why your contract won't compile.

To get rid of this message, you can follow its suggestion and use `.transfer` instead of `.send`:

`msg.sender.transfer(autoBirthFee);`